When will PostgreSQL use /dev/shm?
I have been deploying PostgreSQL 9.4 on Docker for several years, and recently I upgraded the PostgreSQL version to 15.7. However, I have noticed that after upgrading to 15.7, some queries will start reporting the following error: "pq: could not resize shared memory segment"/PostgreSQL XXX "to XXX bytes: No space left on device", this has never happened when I use postgres9.4. I saw some discussions about this, such as questions/275378, questions/56751565, and thread-id/2448119, and I've disabled parallel query for my 15.7 servers, after that the error message did not show again.
So far I know that when using posix shared memory, /dev/shm is used, and posix is the default option for dynamic_shared_memory_type if available. I've also checked on my server: the output of show dynamic_shared_memory_type; is posix, show shared_memory_type; is mmap.
So my questions are:

Does dynamic_shared_memory_type control how parallel queries (and parallel vacuum) use shared memory?
Is parallel query the only operation that uses dynamic_shared_memory_type, if not, what else are there?
Apart from the places affected by dynamic_shared_memory_type and shared_memory_type, are there any other places where posix shared memory is used？


i believe docker still allocates 64 MB of shared memory per container by default. you need to adjust it with --shm-size parameter of docker run or docker create command probably.

@RabbanKeyak Thanks for your advice, if the parallel query is the only thing that uses DSM, disabling it will be ok for now. I will consider adjusting --shm-size.

dynamic_shared_memory_type does not influence how PostgreSQL uses shared memory, it only determines what kind of shared memory is used.
Parallel query is the only thing that uses DSM.
All shared memory usage is using dynamic_shared_memory_type or shared_memory_type (with the exception of a small shared memory segment when the server starts).

Thanks for your quick reply. I'm a bit confused. If parallel queries are the only thing that uses DSM, what is the purpose of the dynamic_shared_memory_type configuration in version 9.4.

It determines what kind of shared memory is used for the dynamic shared memory segments used for parallel query.

But version 9.4 does not support parallel query, does it?

Right. A PostgreSQL extension could make use of it, though.
